# i am not able to redirect to other page when i click the tabs in menu

Tags: html

hi friends i have issue with this code that when i clicked on any tab its not working ... i did not find any issue but still its not working so find solution for me. when i click on the tab it is not redirect to next page it will be in same page... please try to fix

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab"  href="index.html"  
               style="color:#8B008B;font-family: 'Autour One';"><b>Home</b>
              </a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab"  href="familytree.html" 
                  style="color:#8B008B;font-family: 'Autour One';"><b>family 
                    Tree</b></a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="gallery.html" 
         style="color:#8B008B;font-family: 'Autour One';"><b>Gallery</b></a>
                </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: remove data-toggle="tab" from all tag

Comment: but i need to show active status for the clicked tab so i need data-toggle... if i remove the data-toggle then it works but it does not show the active status

Comment: Can you share your website link?

Comment: its not yet hosted... i am just learning so

Comment: We are missing something... you need the data-toggle, but you want to redirect? that is imposible, or redirect or open a tab. Or want to load the page into the tab?

Comment: for ex when i click on the gallery the gallery the  contents of the gallery should be displayed in the same page with active tab that is some color should be displayed on the gallery to to know that we are in the gallery page... i hope i explained you properly... thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the attribute target="_blank". 
For instance:

```
<a href="index.html" target="_blank" font-family:"Autour One"><b>Home</b></a>
```

Comment: if i add target="_blank" it will open in new tab but  i need to show active status for the clicked tab and redirect it that page

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do. But if you want to use data-toggle attribute, you should assign methods such as "toggle", "on" or "enable" to display that it has been clicked and is active.

Comment: where should i enable the toggle?? i mean in style or somewhere else??

Comment: i want to make Active class for clicked tab and if  i insert data-toggle it will show active class for clicked tab but it ll not work.